# I was called for an interview, but now I do not remember the time

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I was contacted by a hiring manager and informed that they would like to have a technical interview. I was really busy with my work and I did answer the phone as I shouldn't miss that. They informed about the interview date and time. But now I don't remember the exact time.

What's the approach to ask the time *without making a bad impression on myself before the interview*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have an email to the hiring manager? You could send them an email:

> Dear Hiring Manager,
>
> Thank you so much for taking the time to speak to me today. I really appreciate the opportunity and hoping to prove that I am the right person for the position at your company.
>
> Could you please confirm the date and the place of the interview, as scheduled via our earlier conversation? Also, could you please give me names of the people I will be meeting with?
>
> Thank you so much,
>
> Jude Niroshan

This way you're not giving a hint you forgot the time and date of the interview, but you just would like to confirm it in the more official way (in writing), and also asking some additional details, as you would like to be prepared to the best of your abilities.

Comment: Unfortunately it was a phone call. Nothing communicated in emails. So, I don't have the recruiter's email address to write back.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan For a phone conversation, I would use a brief introduction but go straight for the content of the second paragraph ("Could you please confirm the date and time of the interview."). You probably don't need to explain why you need that; we've all been on noisy phone connections or suffered background noise during a phone call.

Comment: Exactly what @Brandin said. During this phone call you could also ask them to confirm the interview in writing, via email (you could want to add it to your iCal/Google Calendar/Calendar app). :) Hope that helps!

Comment: @JudeNiroshan Wait, are you working with a recruiter or a hiring manager directly?  That's two different things.  You can ask a recruiter (that is working to get you a job) anything you want.  They have a vested interest in getting you a job, so they work for you to an extent.

Answer (score 2):

You could always kindly ask the person that contacted you to forward you an email containing all the interview details. Stuff like Company address, time of meeting, location (if you don't get someone to pick you up at the reception), contact point in case of unforseen events (this should also contain a phone number or at least an email) so you can contact them if something shows up and you're late or you can't make it.

You could also ask details about the interviewing process, covered technical knowledge asked at the interview (so maybe you could refresh those areas beforehand).

I've never met an interviewer that flat out refused to provide this information (I mean time, location, contact person) in email form or that was offended by my request.

Comment: An extra bonus to this is that if you use Google mail and Google Calendar, you can add it directly to your calendar from the email.